# How to Update blank value in particular field with use of Data Loder?

Tags: community, data-loader, salesforce-id

I want to update field by **Blank** value where Nick Name = "**abcdefg**" in Products.

[image: Product Device NickName]

Answer (score 2):

You need to check "Insert Null Values" checkbox under data loader settings. Please refer below screenshot,
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the null values option in Settings. It's disabled by default to prevent accidental wiping of data. On the initial popup after loading the UI, cancel the wizard, and go to the settings menu option.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you right, you don't want to update all records, you want to update when NickName is a certain value.

The other two answers show you how to update your chosen records, but to get the records you want to update, you need to perform an export.

In the Data Loader, you can export records that meet certain criteria using a standard SOQL query. You can define this query in step 3 of the export process.

Your query will be something like this:

```
SELECT Id, NickName FROM Product2 WHERE NickName = 'abcdefg'
```

After the export, open your CSV file and set NickName to blank for all records.

Finally you need to perform the Update process with the settings described in the other answers, using your CSV file.

**Note** try this in a few records first as a test, just to be sure...